# Select queries joins or group by

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables and I want to make a select statement and show patient first name and bill status and method how he paid and the amount he paid, but I am having a hard time trying to make that query.

`````
```` Create table patient (
```` Patient_ID Number(9) primary key,
```` First_name varchar2(15),
```` Last_name varchar2(10),
```` Contact number(10),
```` City varchar2(20),
```` Doctor_ID Number(9) references Doctor(Doctor_ID));

This is the payment table
`````

`````
````Payment_ID Number(9) primary key,
````Amount Number(10),
````Pyt_Date Date,
````Method varchar2(15),
````PatientID Number(9) references Patient(Patient_ID));

This is the bill table
`````

`````
````Bill_ID Number(9) primary key,
````Status char(10),
````Amount_paid varchar(30),
````Amount_NotPaid varchar(30),
````PatientID Number(9) references Patient(Patient_ID));

This is the query I wrote but it's not working

```` select p.First_name "Patient", Status, method, Amount_paid
```` from patient p and payment on bill 
```` where p.Firstname = status, method = amount_paid
```` group by p.First_name, status, method, amount_paid;
`````

Comment: It looks like your join conditions aren't defined properly at all.  I'd suggest looking up basic information about table joins to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The query you wrote is not syntactically valid. You wrote:

```
select p.First_name "Patient", Status, method, Amount_paid
  from patient p and payment on bill 
  where p.Firstname = status, method = amount_paid
  group by p.First_name, status, method, amount_paid
```

You've got an AND in the FROM clause where it's not allowed, and you're missing an AND in the WHERE clause where it's needed:

```
select p.First_name "Patient", b.Status, b.method, b.Amount_paid
  from patient p,
       bill b
  where p.Firstname = b.status AND
        b.method = b.amount_paid
  group by p.First_name, b.status, b.method, b.amount_paid
```

But I really doubt that's going to do what you want as I doubt very much that the billing method will match the amount paid, or that the patient's first name will match the billing status.

Perhaps what you meant was

```
SELECT p.FIRST_NAME, b.STATUS, y.METHOD, b.AMOUNT_PAID
  FROM PATIENT p
  INNER JOIN BILL b
    ON b.PATIENTID = p.PATIENT_ID
  INNER JOIN PAYMENT y
    ON y.PATIENTID = p.PATIENT_ID
```

It would help if you'd edit your question to include example data for each table, and the results you'd expect from the sample data. Thanks.